Correct usage of "sum" and "mean" for proportions vs continuous variables
What is the proper way to aggregate a measure of "proportions" vs "continuous" by "sum" vs "mean" ?
For example, let's say I have "time_on_site" and "converted". Logically, it makes sense to sum all of the conversions, as we care about the total impact of that variable. But I could also make the case for wanting to improve the conversion rate, as I am interested in capturing a larger proportion of users in my hypothetical widget.
Does this depend on the use-case (this specifically is for AB testing), or is there a general rule of thumb for when to use which aggregation technique?
Please let me know if this question is off-topic; I am interested in the statistically correct aggregation by its use-case.

What you should do almost always depends on what you are trying to find out (i.e. the "use case"). Here, I am wondering why you are aggregating conversions at all. Can one person convert more than once?  What data have you got? What are you trying to find out?

I am aggregating by date here. Basic implementation is an A/B test, so it it has Google Analytics metrics - some continuous such as time on page, time on site; others proportions, such as bounce rate or conversion rate. The question was if one should take the aggregate or the average, but it sounds like it's specific to every situation, and I don't think people here have that knowledge. Thanks!

Remember, the average is just a weighted sum, so they’re similar. As @PeterFlom says, you should define your estimand (the quantity you care about) first as any statistical answer depends on the estimator that results from that definition. E.g. if your estimand is a probability then you probably want a proportion. If its a mean then you want an average, etc.

It depends. Say your widget converts 100% of nes users/visitors, Fantastic?But what if you only get 1 new visitor/user a week? Will you go gloat to your boss? I doubt it. It just means your upstream feed sucks. Now what if your conversion rate is 1/1000. Pretty low? But what if you get 100,000 visitors a day? That is 100 conversions a day; you may want to gloat to your boss (but only because the feed is very good). So which matters more? Both? None? Depends? Yes, depends on the whole context.  Depends on what you are comparing to, what would be worth gloating, etc.

haha, nice. Yes, I realized as you say that sum would really be a measure of upstream factors - if I change my #dopeasswidget on page, that's not creating more users to my site, just affecting their behavior once they are on my site. So it would be mean.
